# How to create an array of TimeZoneInfo variables

Tags: c#

As a beginner in C#, I am trying to improve my code by shortening wherever possible.  I have written a Windows Time Zone application that defines and populates a large number of TimeZoneInfo variables. The problem is there are nearly 90 time zones in use and so my current way of doing this seems cumbersome.  Is it possible to loop using arrays to achieve what 180 lines of code does here?

In addition to brevity, I also want to be able to trap any error caused by a particular time zone not being defined in the user's PC's registry. Having to wrap each TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById() in try catch blocks seems extremely clumsy and not the right way to do this. My thought was that a looping structure would make it much easier to trap a specific error.

```
//Declare the TimeZoneInfo variables: 
TimeZoneInfo tziHawaii;           
TimeZoneInfo tziAlaska;          
TimeZoneInfo tziPacific;           
TimeZoneInfo tziCentral;            
....

// Populate each TimeZoneInfo variable with relevant info:
tziHawaii = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Hawaiian Standard Time");          
tziAlaska = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Alaskan Standard Time");           
tziPacific = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");          
tziCentral = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
....
```

I have attempted to create a looped structure to do what 180 lines of code does above but it doesn't work.  I just cannot see how to create an array of named TimeZoneInfo variables as in the above excerpt (tziHawaii, tziAlaska, etc).

If anyone could point out the error of my ways, I would be very happy.

```
string[] arrWindowsTimeZones = new string[] { "Hawaiian Standard Time", "Alaskan Standard Time", "Pacific Standard Time", "Central Standard Time" };
TimeZoneInfo[] arrTimeZoneInfo = new TimeZoneInfo[] { DON'T KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE} ;

for (int i = 0; i < arrWindowsTimeZones.GetUpperBound(0) + 1; i++)

{
    arrTimeZoneInfo[i] = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(arrWindowsTimeZones[i]);
}
```

Comment: What are you doing with all of the timezones that you need to know which one is Hawaii and which one is Alaska? In other words, how are tziHawaii and tziAlaska used later on?

Comment: @BenJaspers Thanks for your comment. I am building a Windows application that displays the time for each user-selected time zone and the relative time difference between the time zones at any time of the year (daylight savings time of course entering the mix). Difficult to explain but the application makes use of the TimeZoneInfo variables every few seconds to update the times that are displayed by the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones() may be what you want, but if you must do it manually for some reason like you first asked, then this is the code to do it:

```
List<string> arrWindowsTimeZones = new List<string>() { "Hawaiian Standard Time", "Alaskan Standard Time", "Pacific Standard Time", "Central Standard Time" };
List<TimeZoneInfo> arrTimeZoneInfo = new List<TimeZoneInfo>();

foreach (string zoneString in arrWindowsTimeZones)
{
    arrTimeZoneInfo.Add(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(zoneString));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.getsystemtimezones(v=vs.110).aspx) method will return a sorted collection of all the time zones about which information is available on the local system.

From the documentation:

> The GetSystemTimeZones method retrieves all available time zone
>   information from the subkeys of the registry's
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time
>   Zones key. If it is unable to successfully retrieve and parse values
>   for particular string properties of individual TimeZoneInfo objects,
>   this method sets their value to an empty string ("").